# Iterating through each row in a shell variable

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell variable which contains sql results.

```
echo "$sql"
SYSTEM            1000     40.625    /u01/oracle/datafile1.dbf
SYSAUX            1000    67.2375    /u02/oracle/datafile2.dbf
USERS               55 96.3636364    /u03/oracle/datafile3.dbf
UNDOTBS1          1000    98.0625    /u04/oracle/datafile4.dbf
```

I want to apply same processing logic for each row.
**For that I need output like**:

```
1st Iteration
a=SYSTEM          b=1000     c=40.625    d=/u01/oracle/datafile1.dbf
2nd Iteration
 a= SYSTEM        b=1000     c=67.2375   d=/u01/oracle/datafile2.dbf
3rd Iteration
 a= SYSTEM        b=55     c=96.3636364    d=/u01/oracle/datafile3.dbf
4th Iteration
 a= SYSTEM        b=1000     c=98.0625     d=/u01/oracle/datafile4.dbf
```

**Note:**

1. a,b,c,d are variables which will be used for further processing.
2. No of iterations depends on the contents of $sql.

Comment: Are you sure you want `a=SYSTEM` in *each* iteration?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.value of  variable "a" will also change .

Answer (score 1):

This can be done completely in the shell with the `read` and `set` built-ins:

```
#!/bin/sh

sql="SYSTEM            1000     40.625    /u01/oracle/datafile1.dbf
SYSAUX            1000    67.2375    /u02/oracle/datafile2.dbf
USERS               55 96.3636364    /u03/oracle/datafile3.dbf
UNDOTBS1          1000    98.0625    /u04/oracle/datafile4.dbf"

echo "$sql" |
while read line; do
   set -- $line
   a=$1 b=$2 c=$3 d=$4
   # Do something with a,b,c,d (or just use $1, $2, $3, $4.)
   echo "$1 $2 $3 $4"
done
```

Note that this works as long as the words do not contain shell glob characters like '*' (Try it with four `* * * *`). If you need to be robust, you should validate the contents of `$line` before `set`. You might also want to disable filename expansion with `set -f`.

Comment: I tried in cygwin and it is not displaying anything.

Comment: Mahi@Mahi-PC ~
$ echo $0
-bash

Mahi@Mahi-PC ~
$ ./abc.ksh


Mahi@Mahi-PC ~
$ cat abc.ksh
echo "$sql" |
while read line; do
   set -- $line
   a=$1 b=$2 c=$3 d=$4
   # Do something with a,b,c,d (or just use $1, $2, $3, $4.)
   echo "$1 $2 $3 $4"
done

Mahi@Mahi-PC ~
$ echo "$sql"
SYSTEM            1000     40.625    /u01/oracle/datafile1.dbf
SYSAUX            1000    67.2375    /u02/oracle/datafile2.dbf
USERS               55 96.3636364    /u03/oracle/datafile3.dbf
UNDOTBS1          1000    98.0625    /u04/oracle/datafile4.dbf

Mahi@Mahi-PC ~

Comment: @Gunner Yes it does work. I've tested it. You must put this in a script (it won't work if you simply paste it on the command line). Instead of the `echo "$sql" |` you should use `your-sql-command-that-creates-4-words-per-line |`

Comment: thanks a bunch man .Just curious if this can be done with loops and arrays .

Comment: Should be doable, but arrays are non-standard shell features and I don't know anything about ksh arrays. I usually stick to portable POSIX features as shown. This will work in *any* shell and you *will* find yourself one day using a Sun, or Linux, or HP-UX or some other system where things are slightly different. Knowing what works *everywhere* is the path to wisdom.